# Linear interpolation with GL_FLOAT and GL_LUMINANCE?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, linear-interpolation, luminance

I'm developing an app using OpenGL ES 2.0 on an iPad 3. I'm attempting to switch from `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` when calling `glTexImage2D()` to `GL_FLOAT` for "`type`", with `GL_LUMINANCE` as the "`internalFormat`" and "`format`" parameters. (formerly `GL_RGBA`)

The problem: linear interpolation is now gone. When you scale up, it's very pixelated instead of smooth, as it would be with linear interpolation. Do I need to switch to `GL_RGBA` instead of `GL_LUMINANCE`? Does using `GL_LUMINANCE` automatically disable interpolation?

In my shader I start with:

```
highp vec4 tex = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
```

just like I did before when using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. `TexCoordOut` is the interpolated output from the vertex shader. Why isn't it interpolating anymore, after switching to luminance and float?

p.s. I AM calling:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

just before `glTexImage2D()`, but I'm under the impression these calls do nothing anyway under OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just remembered: GL_LINEAR is not available on OpenGL ES 2.0 when GL_FLOAT is used, unless the GL_OES_texture_float_linear extension is supported, which it is not on the iPad 3 and earlier.

Since the GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear extension IS supported, I'll have to look into using that.

Comment: I'm still hoping for help. The specifics of what I'm still needing help with are explained better here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485937/how-to-properly-use-gl-half-float-oes-for-textures